# Prepared Statements in Oracle for SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I am creating a package for incremental Load.

Source= `Oracle DB`

Destination= `MS SQL`

while pulling the data from `Oracle DB` I'm using below query but it is throwing an error.

```
select * from pcarscall1 WHERE [CALLKEY] > ? OR [ModDate] >= ?
```

I know this code works for sql, what I want is an equivalent query for Oracle

Comment: Can you provide some more info.  What is the error message?  Can you run the query directly against Oracle?  Are you running this query inside an SSIS execute query task?  What are the data types for `CALLKEY` and `ModDate`?  Do the parameter data types match?

Comment: CALLKEY=varchar2(255 BYTES),MODDATE=date----
No I am running this query in SSIS source editor.
Error:ORA-00936: missing Expression
Yes Parameter data types match. I can able to load the if i specify exact date but i want to use prepared statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, square brackets around column names are an MS SQL specific extension (only needed for keyword column names or names with spaces) and not recognized by Oracle. Give it a try without the square brackets:

```
select * from pcarscall1 WHERE CALLKEY > ? OR ModDate >= ?
```

Comment: Not sure what happened it started working again.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent for Oracle is to use a quoted identifier:

```sql
select * from pcarscall1 WHERE "CALLKEY" > ? OR "ModDate" >= ?
```

Which means the quoted identifier will be treated as case-sensitive and can contain spaces, other characters that are not typically valid or reserved words.

Or you can use an unquoted identifier:

```sql
select * from pcarscall1 WHERE CALLKEY > ? OR ModDate >= ?
```

Which means that the identifier will (invisibly to the user) be converted to upper-case and your identifiers are (effectively) case-insensitive.